# How to sorted a nested list with float as an element in a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.6, nested-lists

So currently I am learning how to code on HackerRank and one of the problem it asks is to return the name of the student with the second lowest grade. it's a nested list with name(type string) and score(float) as part of a sublist. So an example is:

```
students = [
  ['Harry', 37.21],
  ['Berry', 37.21],
  ['Tina', 37.2],
  ['Akriti', 41],
  ['Harsh', 39]
]
```

Base on the list above the right answer would return 'Harry' and 'Berry.' The code given in the compiler is

```python
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())`
```

and the codes I have added after what was given were `students = []`(after `if __name__ == '__main__':`) `students.append([name, score])` inside the for loop. Lastly I am trying to get it to print the student with the second lowest grade but not really sure how to go about it. Any suggestions? ( I have tried many lines of code with sorted function in it but always get some sort of error, e.g.  `<` not supported between instances of `float` and `str` or `float` object is not iterable or could not convert string to float and vice versa., And sorry since I tried many different lines of code I did not remember which code threw out which error) First, sorry the question has been asked, I've looked up couple different question similar to the one I'm asking but still couldn't really find an answer. Second, sorry if it seems like I'm ranting or complaining, but I have been stuck on this problem for a while now and it's getting depressing because if I get stuck on couple lines of code I'd probably shoot myself if I see a program worthy of codes. Third, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sort()` function with a `key` which tells it to sort using the second element of each of the list inside.

```
students = [['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Tina', 37.2], ['Akriti', 41], ['Harsh', 39]]
students.sort(key = lambda x : x[1])

# students = [['Tina', 37.2], ['Harry', 37.21], ['Berry', 37.21], ['Harsh', 39], ['Akriti', 41]]
print(students[1])
```

Output:

```
['Harry', 37.21]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(sorted(students, key = lambda x : x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A better and a more efficient way would be to push the values into the heap as they come in and then as you get the values out, they are already in a sorted order. And if you're smart, you'll use this fact to only sort once in this problem as well as to finish the problem earlier.

```py
from heapq import heappush

student_scores = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for _ in range(int(input())):
        name = input()
        score = float(input())
        heappush(student_scores, (score, name))
```